# How do I open a Google search link with a new tab using the keyboard?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Previously, I was able to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my Mac using Chrome. However, lately, I noticed that it does not work anymore. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + click still works.

It works by opening that link in a new tab.

To explain what I mean: This is about opening the link after searching. Try searching for something in Google. On the first result, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + click it. It should open that link in a new tab. I want that functionality using a keyboard shortcut without clicking. I used to be able to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and it will work.

What is the new keyboard shortcut for Chrome on Mac?

Comment: This is a recent issue that's described here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451060

Comment: Thanks for the answer flow3d. Can you add this as an answer and someone who googles it can reach this page.

Comment: use Firefox until they fix it! Cmd+Enter works ok there.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> enters the search bar in a new tab. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> closes the tab. It works for me.

For more shortcuts go to: [Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en)

Comment: I meant opening the link after searching. Try searching for something in google. On the first result, cmd + click it. It should open that link in a new tab. I want that functionality using a keyboard shortcut without clicking. I used to be able to cmd + enter and it will work.